# vlookup multiple criteria same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data that is pulled from the web for a popular game. From this data, I would like to create a summary table but the first criteria and second sub-criteria are all in the first column and the data I want to retrieve is in the 5th column. The summary table has the first criteria (Profession) as the header row (B1-L1) and the second criteria (Name) is listed A3 down. The header row is fixed, but the number of (Name) can increase/decrease.
Here is an extract of the data.

```
Name    Race    Class   Level   Skill 
Alchemy (3)                 
Name    Race    Class   Level   Skill 
Poddington          11  1
Ookberg             29  95
Sprowt          100 547
Nothing found.              
Blacksmithing (1)               
Name    Race    Class   Level   Skill 
Fleshdripper            70  70
Nothing found.              
Enchanting (2)              
Name    Race    Class   Level   Skill 
Sprowt          100 609
Mystlibertyx            100 3
Nothing found.
```

etc etc

Column 2 (Race) and column 3 (Class) are blank, 4th column (Level) contains the 1st number which is not required and the 5th column (Skill) contains the 2nd number which is what I would like to retrieve.

So I need a formula that for example in B3 says
Search DATA/col A for Summary/B2 (eg "Alchemy (2)"), then lookup first instance of Summary/A3 (eg "Poddington") and return the Skill number from DATA/column 5, which would be "1", if there is no match then ""

Note, 1) the exact location of the profession "Alchemy" is not fixed.  2) the number of Names within each Profession section does change as members join/leave.  3) 1 name can be listed under 2 different Professions (eg "Sprowt" in above extract).  4) the number in brackets next to the profession is also in column A and will change as (Name)s are added/removed, I already have a formula in row 2 of the summary table that pulls this through, eg =VLOOKUP(B1&"*",'DATA'!$A:$A,1,FALSE)

I am at a loss as how to combine, index/match/find/vlookup whatever to get a result so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first task is to "clean" the data so that you can create an efficient formula.

1. Protect the integrity of the data. Each group heading (Alchemy, Blacksmithing, etc.) must be attached to each record. Insert Column at beginning of sheet (col A). Insert formula in A2 of the new column to check if group has changed or not and record result. Repeat this formula down Column A for the entire record set. IF(Right(c2,1),")",C2,A1). This will add the group heading to every line and change when the group changes
2. Remove all Headers in the record set except for one. Find and Replace all instance of NAME with something like #NAME. In ythis data set I would do the same with the NOTHING FOUND row. Find and Replace with #Nothing.
3. Data can now be sorted. Sort all records on column B. The #Name will be first. Delete all but one of these rows except for one. Next will be #Nothing. Delete these rows as well.

You should now have a clean set of data to work with. My next step would be to pivot the data or create a table of the data for reference purposes.

I think this is what you need but if not please provide an example of what your result table would look like.

Comment: Thanks WCoaster, I can see the advantage to cleaning the data by inserting 2 helper columns, col A is a simple B&C, and col B is using your slightly modified formula =IF(RIGHT(C36,2)=") ",C36,B35), as then I can just use a simple VLOOKUP on the Summary table without touching the integrity of the main data column, =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$2&A3,'DATA'!A:G,7,FALSE),"")

Comment: That sounds good if that you just need a list. This table is also now ready to be referenced in any way you like and much easier to formulate other queries.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to work out what the question is exactly, but as far as I can tell you want to find the next match with a skill name, then go down two rows and across to the fifth column, so (If the name you were searching on was in G2 say) it would be:-

```
=INDEX(A:E,MATCH(G2&"*",A:A,0)+2,5)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for that and this is sort of where I got, but the +2 is not constant and this is where I'm having trouble to then search for the Name before reaching the next "nothing found"

Comment: OK so is it the skill of the  last name you're looking for like 'Sprowt' in the first example? That could be done by searching for 'Alchemy' then 'Nothing' and going back one.

Comment: Hi Tom, Poddington Ookberg and Sprowt are just a few of the character names. Each character can learn 2 main professions (those that end with a number in brackets) out of a possible 11 different professions. Each 'player' can have up to 11 characters within the group so you can see that a fixed formula soon gets very messy. The table I have now got, first looks for the profession and then checks to see if the character is learning that profession and if so, pull in the level they have achieved so far. . . .

Comment: . . . . As per above reply to WCoaster, by inserting the 2 helper columns, I can now use a simple vlookup to retrieve this.